# What is the bondage-like rope Yui Yuigahama from Oregairu is wearing?

Tags: oregairu

I just started watching *Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru*, and the black rope-like object I see on Yui looks like bondage ropes. I doubt it really is, so what is it?

[image]

Just watch the first episode of first season and pay attention to Yui.

Comment: Looking at the picture, it seems to be from the first season. Though I'm not sure if anyone has a few hours to go through all the content in fast forward to find it...

Answer (score 8):

I haven't been able to find an official screenshot showing this, but fan art of Yui seems to be consistent in showing the cords being part of an undershirt with a saw-cut edge:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I won't pretend to be an expert on female clothing, but this was what came to mind when I saw it as well. +1

Answer (score 3):

Here's the official picture from the light novel itself, it's exactly like the pictures from Toshinou.

[image]